# No puedo conectar a la base de datos en línea

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy en un proyecto con un amigo y estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos que está en un servidor. El detalle es que al momento de intentar manejar la base de datos con las hojas de php se queda cargando y lanza un error después de los 30 segundos.

Como es bastante complejo lo que llevo intenté hacer una prueba sencilla para conectarme a la base de datos.

Hice una hoja de conexión:

```
<?php
$mysql_host = "sitio.com";//servidor
$mysql_database="basededatos";//Base de datos
$mysql_user="developer";//usuario
$mysql_password="1234";//contraseña

$conexion=mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database)
or die("Problemas en la conexion a la base de datos");
?>
```

Y una hoja para hacer la consulta:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, correo, contra) VALUES ('Nombre', 'correo@mail.com', '321')")
or die("Error en la alta".mysqli_error($conexion));

echo "Alta realizada";
?>
```

El detalle es que al momento de ejecutar la hoja se queda cargando también y me lanza el mismo error de antes que es el siguiente:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexi�n ya que la parte conectada no respondi�
>   adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en
>   la conexi�n establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido
>   responder. in C:\xampp\htdocs\redapp\conexion.php on line 7
>       Problemas en la conexion a la base de datos

No tengo idea de lo que pueda ser ya que puedo conectarme al servidor por ftp (FileZilla), y también me conecto a la base de datos con MySQL Workbench sin problemas. Creo que lo único que falla al momento de conectarme a la base de datos es el php y no entiendo el porque. Por cierto, el servidor se encuentra en un ordenador que nosotros tenemos en casa.

Busqué el código del error y no vi algo que solucione lo mío.

De antemano agradezco el apoyo.

Comment: Hola Raúl. Las pruebas que yo haría... Has hecho ping desde tu equipo al equipo servidor a ver si hay conectividad? Has probado de poner la IP en vez del alias en el mysql_host?

Comment: No pensé en eso porque puedo conectarme al servidor por MySQL Workbench.
A parte tenemos un archivo html que el navegador sí puede abrir.

Comment: No he probado lo de cambiar del alias a la IP, cuando tenga la oportunidad lo voy a intentar.

Comment: Ya lo probé, no soluciona el problema cambiar el alias del servidor por el IP.
Me cercioré de que fuera la IP correcta.